# in Azure Data Factory, How to see output data for a Lookup activity in debug mode?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, etl, azure-data-factory

I am doing a lookup on a CSV file with 5 rows. When I debug my pipeline I want to see the rows read by lookup activity when I click on the 'output' arrow. Please see attached screenshot.[image]

However, after clicking on the above icon I am getting the following result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to preview the file data from look up settings just like below?

[image: Preview Option]

If not, make sure you point to the file in data set.

Once you are able to preview, in the output also you can find the rows as below

Output

```json
{
    "count": 4,
    "value": [
        {
            "sno": "1",
            "name": "tendulkar,sachin",
            "age": "42"
        },
        {
            "sno": "2",
            "name": "ar,rahman",
            "age": "50"
        },
        {
            "sno": "3",
            "name": "mk,stalin",
            "age": "65"
        },
        {
            "sno": "4",
            "name": "poet,vairamuthu",
            "age": "70"
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am able to preview the data. I have made sure it's connecting to the right dataset. But still it's now showing the CSV file content in the output section.

Comment: Sorry, is it working ? If not can you pls post more details on your source settings